# Does Cassandra allow user defined function in where clause?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh, cassandra-3.0

I created user defined function `fStringToDouble` which takes string as an argument and returns double. This user defined functions works fine in select statement.

```
SELECT applieddatetime, fStringToDouble(variablevalue)  from my_table WHERE locationid='xyz' and applieddatetime >= '2016-08-22' AND applieddatetime < '2016-08-23' ;
```

When I put this user defined function in where clause , I get syntax error as `"no viable alternative at input"`

```
SELECT applieddatetime from my_table WHERE locationid='xyz' and applieddatetime >= '2016-08-22' AND applieddatetime < '2016-08-23'and fStringToDouble(variablevalue)<6.0;
```

What is wrong with above query ? Is there any built in function to cast String to Double in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use user defined function in WHERE clauses but only some range query operators.

If you want to know more about what you can do in WHERE clauses, you can have a look at this post: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause